# when i try to do a file repository via Amazon S3 i can't connect to localhost: 8000

Tags: scala, amazon-s3, playframework, sbt, http-error

I'am working on a scala project with play framework , when i try to do a file repository via Amazon S3 i can't connect to localhost: 8000 ; here is the exception I get :

com.amazonaws.SdkClientException: Unable to execute HTTP request: Connect to localhost:8000

Would you please help me to resolve that problem

Comment: Are you using a Proxy? Maybe you need to configure it for the proxy

Comment: Yeah sure there is a proxy , but how to deal with that , can you help ?  @GamingFelix

Comment: Do you know what's the proxy you need to go through? It was a while ago since I used play, but I guess you can configure that in the play settings. It probably depends on the version you're using, but here's an example of someone else asking the same question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30522747/change-proxy-settings-in-play-framework